# How to make nav bar transparent with white font?

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to make my `UINavigationBar` to look like this:[image]

If I tap on the translucent `UIButton` in Xcode, it's not translucent. The only solution is to set the `alpha` value to 0.5, but then I won't have my font opaque and the navigation items as on this image. So I think I am looking for translucent and blur effects.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a image lying underneath the Navigationbar? Because when I activate translucency, it works as expected. Maybe you just cannot see the effect, because you have nothing under the navigationbar

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu So I need to place for example white rectangle to navbar and checked translucent?

Comment: no. Your content view under the navigationbar needs a background image.

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu Yes, I have an image under navigation bar. So what should I have checked? Style = Default, Translucent checked, Bar Tint = Default? Under view option - Alpha = 1, Background = Default, Drawing-Opaque = not checked?

Comment: is your image really under the navigationbar or just below it?  can you provide a screenshot? maybe from the viewdebugger

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu I have edited my question. Now it is translucent, but still too dark. Maybe I am asking wrong question. Youradio has a blurred and translucent background. Is it just image or can I simulate it in Xcode?

Comment: @Kotora Does the nav bar look different for different song art? - If so, did you try UIBlurEffect?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't have a Youradio app, I just want to archieve the same effect. This code in Swift gives me EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in the line visualEffectView.frame = bounds.

Answer (score 2):

I had no trouble getting this, simply as a black translucent nav bar:

[image]

It is definitely a dark blurred version of what's behind it; look how it's brighter on the right, where there's a bright patch in the picture.

I can get a gentler blur by using a clear navigation bar with a visual effect view behind it:

[image]

What *they* are actually using, however, is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is matter of background. As I wrote, I've asked wrong question. I want to make navigation bar with effect of frozen glass. So translucented and blurred. Maybe I need to use Visual Effect With Blur on the background of UITableView?

Comment: I do not know what "the effect of frozen glass" is!

Comment: And you do not think that my visual effect view is doing that? Is it because there is too much blur?

Comment: I think it is too opaque. Is there a way to make it look like real frozen glass? So (maybe) white color and very translucent (just like in the image)?

Comment: There has to be a bug in Xcode. Why the hell the background is black? I have selected: Style-Default, Translucent, Bar Tint-Clear Color and that bloody UINavigationBar is black!

Comment: Well, you could take a snapshot of the region behind the nav bar and then you could blur it however you want with a CIFilter. But course then it is not "live" - it is a blurred frozen image.